# Highcharts Doesn't Refresh at Colorbox but Automatically Refreshes When Inspected at Firebug

Tags: highcharts, colorbox

I have highcharts graphic at my main HTML. I put it in a small div so some parts of graphics is not showed. When user clicks a button it opens at colorbox as a popup however doesn't refresh its size. When I click to inspect with Firebug it suddenly refresh its size and everything is normal. When I close colorbox it it still big and I can not see many part of the graphic too.

Is there any idea about how to refresh Highcharts graphic and why it is refreshing itself(what I want) just when I click inspect element with Firebug?

**PS:** It works when I resize the windows not related to Firebug. There is something here seems same problem with mine: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called window.resize after data loaded and after colorbox closed, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example to look at its hard to tell, but here is what I think is happening:

First check if the option [reflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.reflow) is set to true. If it is then Highcharts will monitor window.resize events and redraw itself when a resize occurs. My guess is that when activating Firebug, the window is resized and the chart is redrawn.

If you want to manually set a new size of the chart you can use the api method [setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize%28%29). To only redraw the chart you should use [redraw()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw%28%29).

Comment: For reflow it is set to true by default. I can not get chart object from my other js, I am looking for a generic solution for my issue.

Comment: What I described is how Highcharts treats resize events and how to do a resize manually. I don't know how to help you further without an example to look at.